# How to make rgbdemo working with non-kinect stereo cameras?

Tags: c++, opencv, mesh, point-cloud-library, 3d-reconstruction

I was trying to get [RGBDemo](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectRgbDemoV6)(mostly reconstructor) working with 2 logitech stereo cameras, but I did not figure out how to do it.

I noticed that there is a opencv grabber in [nestk](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectUseNestk) library and its header file is included in the reconstructor.cpp. Yet, when I try "rgbd-viewer --camera-id 0", it keeps looking for kinect.

My questions:
1. Is RGBDemo only working with kinect so far?
2. If RGBDemo can work with non-kinect stereo cameras, how do I do that?
3. If I need to write my own implementation for non-kinect stereo cameras, any suggestion on how to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with non-kinect cameras. You don't even need stereo. There are algorithms now that are able to determine whether two images' viewpoints are sufficiently different that they can be used as if they were taken by a stereo camera. In fact, they use images from different cameras that are found on the internet and reconstruct 3D models of famous places. I can write you a tutorial on how to get it working. I've been meaning to do so. The software is called Bundler. Along with Bundler, people often also use CMVS and PMVS. CMVS preprocesses the images for PMVS. PMVS generates dense clouds.

BUT! I highly recommend that you don't go this route. It makes a lot of mistakes because there is so much less information in 2D images. It makes it very hard to reconstruct the 3D model. So, it ends up making a lot of mistakes, or not working. Although Bundler and PMVS are awesome compared to previous software, the stuff you can do with kinect is on a whole other level.

To use kinect will only cost you $80 for the kinect off of ebay or $99 off of amazon and another $5 for the power adapter off of amazon. So, I'd highly recommend this route. Kinect provides much more information for the algorithm to work with than 2D images do, making it much more effective, reliable and fast. In fact, it could take hours to process images with Bundler and PMVS. Whereas with kinect, I made a model of my desk in just a few seconds! It truly rocks!